# T-SQL: How do I run the same SQL codes 4 times and record the results for all 4 runs?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a temp table that looks like:

```
if object_id (N'tempdb..#a') is not null drop table #a

select customer_id, rand() as random_rank into #a from customer
select * from #a
```

And the result would look like this for this run:

| customer_id | rand_rank |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 95 |
| 3 | 71 |

However, I need to rerun the SQL code from the top 4 times, so the output I would expect would look like this:

| customer_id | run1 | run2 | run3 | run4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 16 | 12 | 67 |
| 2 | 95 | 52 | 11 | 32 |
| 3 | 71 | 89 | 44 | 97 |

I am just using 4 runs for simplification but I'll mostly like need to run this iteration 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

Create the temp table, and add a run_num column to it.

Then in your select do

```
INSERT INTO #a (customer_id, rand_rank, run_num) 
SELECT customer_id, rand(), 1
  FROM customer
```

then if you need to format that into a single table with all the runs, you can do something like

```
SELECT customer_id
       CASE WHEN run_num = 1 THEN rand_rank ELSE NULL END as run1,
       CASE WHEN run_num = 2 THEN rand_rank ELSE NULL END as run2,
       CASE WHEN run_num = 3 THEN rand_rank ELSE NULL END as run3
  FROM #a
```